# How to manage retrofit between multiple android modules

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I need to understand how can i manage retrofit between multiple modules in an android application where each module talk to different server. My focus here is that all modules should benefit from the cache but each module may have a different configuration (ie. headers and base_url).

Ex:

I've 3 sub modules in a android project.
submodule1 depends on submodule2
submodle3 depends on submodule2

submodule1 talks to server1
submodule2 talks to server2
submodule3 talks to server3

is it ok to have single instance of retrofit and change the configuration on demand OR is there any other solution to this ?

Comment: Building a retrofit instance is a costly operation. Perhaps it is better to have 3 different onces

Comment: Did you use Dagger for dependencies injection?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using different Retrofit instance and Connectors for different modules :

```
public static NetworkConnector getRetrofit1() {
    if (ZivaURLs.retrofitNetworkHandler1 == null) {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonDateDeSerializer());
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ZivaURLs.HOST_1)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder.create()))
                .build();
        retrofit.client().setReadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        retrofit.client().setWriteTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        retrofit.client().setConnectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ZivaURLs.retrofitNetworkHandler1 = retrofit.create(NetworkConnector1.class);
    }
    return ZivaURLs.retrofitNetworkHandler1;
}
```

Now I am using different Connector interface for every module just to make my code cleaner, and easy to change/upgrade.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I'll validate this and mark your answer accordingly.

Comment: @pavankumar please mark the answer if it was helpful for you.